# fullcalendar.io settings in existing project

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, mediawiki-extensions

I try to use [fullcalendar.io](http://fullcalendar.io) in the [Cargo](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Cargo) extension for MediaWiki. I would like to set other locales, but as a noob in JS, I can't find a proper way to do that. [Docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/locale/) says that another script has to be executed f.e. `<script src='fullcalendar/locale/es.js'></script>`, but I have no idea where I should use it in the Cargo [source files](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:ExtensionDistributor?extdistname=Cargo&extdistversion=REL1_29).
Could you please help with it?

Unfortunately locales configuration via Cargo display settings is not available.

EDIT:
Main configuration file Cargo.php is loading extensions. A part of code for calendar is:

```
'ext.cargo.calendar' => array(
        'styles' => array(
            'libs/fullcalendar.css',
            'libs/ext.cargo.calendar.css',
        ),
        'scripts' => array(
            'libs/fullcalendar.js',
            'libs/ext.cargo.calendar.js',
        ),
        'dependencies' => array(
            'moment',
        ),
        'position' => 'top',
        'localBasePath' => __DIR__,
        'remoteExtPath' => 'Cargo'
```

I tried to add `'libs/locale/es.js',` in the last position in scripts array, but it doesn't work.

Comment: well, how are you using the rest of the fullCalendar within this extension? How do you include the other scripts for that? I don't know Cargo but I could guess that maybe you include the extra locale script in just the same way as you did the fullCalendar, momentJS and jQuery scripts which are required. That would seem logical. Unless there is something about this extension which makes that difficult in some way?

Comment: In the main Cargo.php file there is a section which loads extensions. A part of it which is for calendar looks like: `'ext.cargo.calendar' => array(
  'styles' => array(
   'libs/fullcalendar.css',
   'libs/ext.cargo.calendar.css',
  ),
  'scripts' => array(
   'libs/fullcalendar.js',
   'libs/ext.cargo.calendar.js',
  ),
  'dependencies' => array(
   'moment',
  ),
  'position' => 'top',
  'localBasePath' => __DIR__,
  'remoteExtPath' => 'Cargo'`

Comment: ok so you can just add the locale file to the scripts array in that snippet? Or maybe Cargo exposes a method by which you can add extra stuff to the standard config?

Comment: For the first question, I just answered above - it doesn't change locales. For the second, I tried to find it, but it is first time I read JS code and I don't see any way to do that :(

Comment: that isn't JS,it's PHP (hence it's in Cargo.php). Is there nothing in the documentation which might explain it? P.S. When the final page is rendered to the browser, does it include the local file in the rendered markup or not (you can use View Source in the browser to check)?

Comment: Cargo documentation only informs that I can change only: 
width, height, start date, view, color and text color when I create calendar instantion.
I see in the View Source $wgCargoMonthNames with my language month names, but it is still displayed in English.

Comment: what about the actual es.js? Is there a reference to that in the View Source? That's what I was referring to. Presumably there are references to fullCalendar.js etc.

Comment: I checked for all ".js" in the source. There is only one, not related to the calendar extension.

Comment: how is it managing to get fullCalendar to work then? Perhaps this one big JS file combines all the others into one? Did you look in it?

Comment: I see there a very long line which looks like `<div class="cargoCalendar" dataurl="http://192.168.0.20/wiki/index.php?title=Specjalna:CargoExport&amp;tables%........format=fullcalendar........` (dots are replacing many other fields) so for me it looks that it works through MediaWiki Special Pages mechanism (Specjalna:CargoExport)